# can I use two ssh java lib in my java code?

Tags: java, ssh, j2ssh

I am using j2ssh but due to some reasons (which we cant detect yet) we decided to switch to new ssh lib.

in j2ssh for 2 functions which are not giving expected result, we have to switch to new ssh (i have found vngx-jsch suitable)

but only for 2 functions, i need to do full rework of all ssh related function which i dont want to. 
 so I have following queries : -

1. can I use both lib ?
2. does it make sense ?
3. what if I keep j2ssh as it is and only for those 2 function I will load vngx-ssh?
4. is it possible?
5. how to do it ? any example ?

Comment: Sure, unless they both rely on competing versions of something else, but why?

Comment: sry , but i dont understand ur answer. competing versions of something else means? j2ssh and vngx-jsch both are different java ssh libs both has similar functions to support sftp etc.

Comment: Competing versions of another JAR that they both rely on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, It's possible. you can use the fully qualified names to resolve the conflicts. for example:

let say there are 2 packages, `com.package1.A` and `com.package2.B` which exports the same function, `func()`. In your Java program, you can use any one of these by calling either

```
package com.package1;

public class A {
    public void func() {
       System.out.println("Inside A package's func ");
    }
}
```

And the second is:

```
package com.package2;

public class B {
    public void func() {
       System.out.println("Inside B package's func ");
    }
}
```

Then in a separate class you can use it like:

```
public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        com.package1.A.func();
        com.package2.B.func();
}
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for answer, i understood the thing, one ques - i have included both jars now suppose only for 2 functions i have applied fully qualified names (in my case with vngx-jsch) is it sufficient or other place i have to mention with j2ssh ?

Comment: that should work. no need to change in other places.

Comment: and also if you think the answer was useful and answered your question, vote "up" and mark it complete :)

Comment: you should be able to see arrow mark just above the "0", clicking on that means that the answer was useful

Answer (score 1):

> 1) can I use both lib ?

Probably yes.  But you would need to try it to be sure.

The two things that would be contra-indicative would be:

- the two libraries defining classes with the same fully qualified class names<sup>1</sup>, or
- needing to accept ssh connections in your application using the two libraries using the same port.

> 2) does it make sense ?

Possibly.  But IMO, it *makes more sense* to either find and fix the root problem<sup>2</sup>, or recode the application so that it does need the two missing functions.

> 3) what if I keep j2ssh as it is and only for those 2 function I will load vngx-ssh? is it possible?

It depends what you mean.  If you make separate connections using the two libraries then that could work.

> how to do it ? any example ?

It depends on the details of your problem.  (But you are unlikely to find examples, because what you are doing sounds like an inferior approach ...)

---

<sup>1 - If this is a problem, it may be possible to work around the name clash using classloader magic, but you should only do that as a last resort.</sup>

<sup>2 - This is one of the advantages of open source.  If there is a problem in the application / library you are using, you can find it and fix it ... and then contribute your fix back to the community.</sup>

Comment: What question are you talking about?